# Receber data do datapicker

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data, datepicker, textbox

Estou a criar um site no qual tenho um datapicker com recurso ao seguinte [site](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) 
Queria que quando fosse guardar ir buscar a data que foi escolhida do datapicker que aparece em vez da data da textbox.

Comment: Bom dia, ao carregar a sua página o Datepicker já carregar setando a text que ele vai manipular, então você terá que pegar os dados dessa text... sua dúvida é essa mesmo?

Comment: Não entendi o que quis dizer

Comment: Você já implementou o Datepicker no seu projeto?

Comment: já  sim implementei o do site em cima referido

Comment: e vocês esta armazenando em uma TextBox correto?

Comment: sim. Mas não quero converter o que está na textbox pois irá ser uma string e depois muda a data conforme o país. queria era pegar a data do próprio calendário e não da textbox

Comment: Dá de alguma forma para ir buscar o valor do calendário que aparece quando se clica na textbox?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [receber data do datapicker como um Date](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295620/receber-data-do-datapicker-como-um-date)

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, segue abaixo um código que possivelmente seja o que você esteja procurando. O código alem de mostrar a data formatada no campo "datepicker" no "alternate" ele mostra sem formatar, deixa original.
link para documentação: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Populate alternate field</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      altField: "#alternate",
      altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">&nbsp;<input type="text" id="alternate" size="30"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: não eu pretendo ter na mesma o dd/mm/yyyy mas em vez de ser passado por string ser passado por . date, .getdate ou algo parecido que passe a data

Comment: Você já olhou na documentação se a função passa "Date", eu creio que ela já passa como string e por isso você terá que converter quando for enviar seus dados...

Comment: e converto por TryParse?

Comment: Sim, pois ele vai converter para o local da aplicação... Inglês, Francês, Brasil.... não e isso que você quer?