# receber data do datapicker como um Date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data, datepicker

Coloquei no meu site em asp.net o datepicker deste [site](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) e quero receber o valor como **Date** em vez de String , para que não dê problemas com o tipo de data de outros países.

```js
/* Brazilian initialisation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
/* Written by Leonildo Costa Silva (leocsilva@gmail.com). */
( function( factory ) {
 if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {

  // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
  define( [ "../widgets/datepicker" ], factory );
 } else {

  // Browser globals
  factory( jQuery.datepicker );
 }
}( function( datepicker ) {

datepicker.regional[ "pt-BR" ] = {
 closeText: "Fechar",
 prevText: "&#x3C;Anterior",
 nextText: "Próximo&#x3E;",
 currentText: "Hoje",
 monthNames: [ "Janeiro","Fevereiro","Março","Abril","Maio","Junho",
 "Julho","Agosto","Setembro","Outubro","Novembro","Dezembro" ],
 monthNamesShort: [ "Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai","Jun",
 "Jul","Ago","Set","Out","Nov","Dez" ],
 dayNames: [
  "Domingo",
  "Segunda-feira",
  "Terça-feira",
  "Quarta-feira",
  "Quinta-feira",
  "Sexta-feira",
  "Sábado"
 ],
 dayNamesShort: [ "Dom","Seg","Ter","Qua","Qui","Sex","Sáb" ],
 dayNamesMin: [ "Dom","Seg","Ter","Qua","Qui","Sex","Sáb" ],
 weekHeader: "Sm",
 dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
 firstDay: 0,
 isRTL: false,
 showMonthAfterYear: false,
 yearSuffix: "" };
datepicker.setDefaults( datepicker.regional[ "pt-BR" ] );

return datepicker.regional[ "pt-BR" ];

} ) );

$(function() {  
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Alguém me consegue ajudar?

Comment: A sua pergunta é vaga, qual é o código ?

Comment: está no site que deixei em cima, mas segue aqui tambem  "<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>

 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>"

Comment: para receber o valor do datepicker é que não sei o código daí estar a questionar

Comment: Eu coloquei na pergunta sua o exemplo do código está em inglês, e você queria a data em portugues?

Comment: Não. Eu quero em vez de receber em string ser em date para que independentemente do sitio do mundo onde o site seja executado não existam erros no formato da data

Comment: Para onde você está executando isso... está mandando o valor pra onde? isso que eu não entendi!

Comment: Para guardar a data de nascimento na base de dados

Comment: se tem que colocar esse código!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76911/discussion-between-jose-gomes-and-virgilio-novic).

Answer (score 0):

Boa dia, segue abaixo um código que possivelmente seja o que você esteja procurando. O código alem de mostrar a data formatada no campo "datepicker" no "alternate" ele mostra sem formatar, deixa original.
link para documentação: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field
Como o DatePicker retorna a data como string você terá que converter a data no backend, antes de mandar pro banco, usando o método TryParse.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Populate alternate field</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      altField: "#alternate",
      altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">&nbsp;<input type="text" id="alternate" size="30"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```